# Minimimtrackimage alignment issues in swift

Tags: ios, swift

I’m trying to create a waveform player similar to soundcloud, the minimum track image I set for the slider originally kept stretching to the slider button itself. I wanted it perfectly aligned with the maximumtrackimage so I users the code:

```
Image.ResizableImage(withCapInsets:UIEdgeInsets:0,0,0,0)
```

**Screen shot**

[image: Screen shot]

Which made the image stretch out past the slider button to the whole slider track itself, which is what I wanted but the problem is that the image is passing the slider track and I want it to resize from the beginning of the slider track to the end.

Comment: Why not just put the wave form drawing _behind_ the slider as a separate view? That would give you much more power and precision than trying to jam it _into_ the slider in this funny way.

Comment: Because I want it to track with the slider revealing the orange track image as the player plays.

Comment: Yep, I understand that, but you can easily redraw or mask the track image as the player plays. In fact I'm not convinced that a slider is the best implementation in the first place. You might be better off building your own UIControl if you need draggability (do you?).

Comment: Yes I do need dragability...is not sure how to accomplish what you are recommending, unfortunately my skills are not the greatest.

Answer (score 0):

I can't quite remember what the SoundCloud interface looks like, but I seem to recall it's something like this:

[image]

I generated that effect easily without using any slider. In general it's probably best to do things the easy way, constructing your own interface rather than trying to bend some existing interface element (such as your slider) to some purpose for which it was never intended.

My interface consists of two image views, a red version of the sound "wave" with a black version laid on top of it. The "transition" from black to red is performed by sliding a layer mask sideways over the black version of the image view, thus revealing the red version which was hidden behind it.

So all you would have to do is coordinate the position of the layer mask with the position being played within the song. If you wanted to use this as a scrubber, you would just detect the user's finger within the image view and do the same thing.